# jquery and ajax in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I just want to display a content from database when click a button in codeigniter,

here is my script

```
function check()
{

    var base_url="<?php echo base_url();?>"; 
    $.ajax({
    url :  base_url+"/seller/getSubCategory", success : function(data)
    {$('#content').html(data);}});
}
```

in controller.php

```
public function getSubCategory()
    {
        $data['result']=$this->propertydetails->getPropertyCategories();
        $this->load->view('seller/postdetails',$data);
    }
```

and here is model.php

```
<?php
class propertydetails extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }   
    function getPropertyCategories()
    {
        $query=$this->db->get('orx_categories');
        if($query->result()>0)
        {
            return $query->result();
        }
        else 
        {
            return $query->result();
        }   
    }
}

?>
```

when i run this code nothing is happening, it doesn't show any errors, and it returns nothing.
help me to solve this?

Comment: doublecheck your baseurl.  Make sure the generated url is correct.

Comment: i have checked my url many times and i have been trying the code with direct url that is http://localhost/thebrokerhunt/index.php/seller/getSubCategory but still have the problem. i would be more thankful if anyone give me the sample code to get values from database using jquery and ajax in codeigniter

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't do $query->result() > 0 because $query->result() is an array. More appropriate would be count($query->result()) > 0. What does your view look like? How are you calling the Javascript? Sometimes when you get stuck, it's something really simple like making a syntax error in the JS which prevents it from executing...

Comment: i want to say this, i have used the same getPropertyCategories() somewhere in my code there i have get the results, one more thing is if i display a alert message at the beginning of the check method, its working fine if i display a alert message at the end of check it would not display, i thing the error is in ajax part...please help me....

Comment: <html>
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function check()
{
 
 var base_url="<?php echo base_url();?>";
 alert(base_url+"index.php/seller/getSubCategory"); 
  $.ajax({
 url :  base_url+"index.php/seller/getSubCategory", success : function(data)
 {$('#content').html=data;}});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"> i want to display a text from database</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: What happens if you navigate to that URL directly?

Answer (score 0):

I've found Charles Proxy invaluable when debugging ajax requests:
http://www.charlesproxy.com/
I would also double check that url helper is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic example of what you can try, this assumes that you have a form and you want to use that post data, alternatively you could do something like (".button").click(...

Once the data has been pulled back from the query you can load a view into a variable rather then sending it directly to be output by setting the third parameter of the view loader to true. by doing this you can send multiple views back to the page and it avoids forcing you to write html in the controller.

Javascript code

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post("base_url+"/controller/method", $("#form").serialize(),
        function(data){
        if(data.status == "valid"){
            $(".view1").html(data.view1);
            $(".view2").html(data.view2);
        }
        }, "json");
    });
});
```

And your php controller

```
class Controller extends CI_Controller {
public function method()
   {
      $this->load->model('Some_model','', TRUE);
      $data['results'] = $this->Some_model->some_function();
      if($data['results']['status'] == "valid"){
         $json['status'] = "valid";
         $json['view1'] = $this->load->view('view1',$data,true);
         $json['view2'] = $this->load->view('view2',$data,true);
         echo json_encode($json);
      }
      else {
         $json['status'] = "invalid";
         $json['error'] = "<h3>Login Failed</h3>";
         echo json_encode($json);
      }
   }
}
```

and your php model

```
class Some_model extends CI_Model {
public function some_function()
   {
      $query=$this->db->get('orx_categories');
      if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
         $sata['status'] = "valid";
         foreach($sql->result() as $row) {
            $data['results'][] = $row;
         }   
      }
      else {
         $data['status'] = "invalid";
      }
      return $data;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the controller function when loading a view pass a third boolean parameter true. which means ok get that view and store it in a variable not render it then echo that variable value.
see below code of the controller function

```
public function getSubCategory()
{
    $data['result']=$this->propertydetails->getPropertyCategories();

    //note the third parameter to the view method
    //it means get the content of the seller/postdetails view and store it
    //in a local variable $output
    $output = $this->load->view('seller/postdetails',$data,true);
   //now echo the $output so that the javascript function can consume
   echo $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your script to

```
function check() {

     var base_url="<?php echo base_url();?>"; 
     $.ajax({
          url : "<?php echo base_url();?>/seller/getSubCategory", 
          success : function(data){
                  $('#content').html(data);
          }
     });
 }
```

change your controller to :

```
public function getSubCategory()
    {
        $data = $this->propertydetails->getPropertyCategories();
        echo $data;
    }
```